# Sql query doesnt execute correcly (where)

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have a little problem executing sql query.

In my bd I have 3 column (experimentID, applicationID, intent)

I want to get some specific intent with experimentID = 3

my query is :

```
SELECT experimentID, applicationID, intent 
from intents 
WHERE experimentID = 3 AND intent='android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE' OR intent='android.intent.action.ALL_APPS' OR intent='android.intent.action.ANSWER' OR intent='android.intent.action.APPLICATION_PREFERENCES' OR intent='android.intent.action.APPLICATION_RESTRICTIONS_CHANGED' OR intent='android.intent.action.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE' OR intent='android.intent.action.APP_ERROR' OR intent='android.intent.action.ASSIST' OR intent='android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE' OR intent='android.intent.action.ATTACH_DATA' OR intent='android.intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF' OR intent='android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED' OR intent='android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED_ACTION' OR intent='android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW' OR intent='android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService' OR intent='android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON' OR intent='android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE' OR intent='android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY' OR intent='android.intent.action.START_SMS_SERVICE' OR intent='android.app.action.ACTION_DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED' OR intent='android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED' OR intent='android.intent.action.BUG_REPORT' OR intent='android.intent.action.CALL' OR intent='android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE' OR intent='android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON' OR intent='android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON' OR intent='android.intent.action.CARRIER_SETUP';
```

The problem is that I get also others experimentID...(not only experimentID = 3)

I think it's because of the `OR` in the query but how can I do the query to get only experiementID = 3? The problem is obviously in the `WHERE`

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You need to put all the intent in parentheses to solve this

Comment: So if expirementID = 4 would the intent values be the same or do you have a different list?  Does the list of intents vary based on experiementID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parentheses can solve the problem.  But a better solution is `in`:

```
SELECT experimentID, applicationID, intent
FROM intents
WHERE experimentID = 3 AND
      intent IN ('android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE', 
                 . . .
                 'android.intent.action.CARRIER_SETUP'
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT experimentID, applicationID, intent 
from intents 
WHERE experimentID = 3 
((AND intent='android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE')( OR intent='android.intent.action.ALL_APPS' OR intent='android.intent.action.ANSWER' OR intent='android.intent.action.APPLICATION_PREFERENCES' OR intent='android.intent.action.APPLICATION_RESTRICTIONS_CHANGED' OR intent='android.intent.action.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE' OR intent='android.intent.action.APP_ERROR' OR intent='android.intent.action.ASSIST' OR intent='android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE' OR intent='android.intent.action.ATTACH_DATA' OR intent='android.intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF' OR intent='android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED' OR intent='android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED_ACTION' OR intent='android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW' OR intent='android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService' OR intent='android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON' OR intent='android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE' OR intent='android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY' OR intent='android.intent.action.START_SMS_SERVICE' OR intent='android.app.action.ACTION_DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED' OR intent='android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED' OR intent='android.intent.action.BUG_REPORT' OR intent='android.intent.action.CALL' OR intent='android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE' OR intent='android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON' OR intent='android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON' OR intent='android.intent.action.CARRIER_SETUP'));
```